# Angular2 + nodeJS + MongoDB +?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular2

Совсем недавно столкнулся с Angular2 понравился он мне в качестве FRONTEND разработки и насколько понял в плане быстродействия выигрывает nodeJS Хотелось бы узнать как это можно все совместить. Имеются предположения что не до конца все изучил и подключать лишнего не надо. Но вопрос, мне к примеру нужны роуты + middleware, так же ORM и все это надо как то связать?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем чёткий вопрос.
Для бэкэнда на node есть 2 основных фреймворка Express и Koa. В них есть все что вам может потребоваться.
Для работы с Angular2 лучше использовать Angular CLI.
Таким образом у вас будет запускаться сервер для фронта на одном порте и сервер для бэка на другом. 
На бэкэнде нужно будет настроить CORS (установка 1 пакета).